# Schematic floor plan design in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating a ASP.NET MVC 4 project and within this project I want to create a schematic of our production floor and be able to add in data (for example Head Board Assembly has 40 Jobs), so basically an overlay of where data can be added and updated.

I was wondering how to go about creating a schematic design or even overlay data over an image (I can draw out the floor plan on Photoshop).

Any ideas or help is appreciated :)

Comment: I'd just use Office Visio for this. It has built-in support for interfacing with data-sources.

Comment: good shout! i added it in as a SVG too :) thanks @Dai, now i need some way to add textbox overlays to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved using a SVG image from visio